# Increasing external crystal value on STM32F407, what does it affect?

Tags: stm32

STM32F407 can run at maximum speed(168 MHz) with 8 MHz oscillator . So, what does it change if it is used with a 16 MHz or 25 MHz oscillator?

EDIT::
Exactly what I wanted to ask: We can reach 168 MHz speed with an externally mounted 8 Mhz oscillator. Why use a 25 MHz crystal when we can achieve this speed with an 8 MHz oscillator?

Comment: Two questions: have you read the data sheet and the user's manual, and do you mean _crystal_ (a two-pin thing that's dead until you wrap it with an oscillator circuit), or a crystal _oscillator_ (a three- or four-pin thing that has a crystal in it, but also an oscillator circuit, to which you apply power and get a digital clock signal).

Comment: Exactly what I wanted to ask: We can reach 168MHz speed with an externally mounted 8 Mhz crystal oscillator. Why use a 25MHz crystal when we can achieve this speed with an 8MHz crystal?

Comment: You appear to be using "crystal" and "crystal oscillator" interchangeably.  Many people get these confused.  **Please clarify which of these distinctly different devices you are talking about**.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from this screen cap from STM32CubeMX configurator the clock subsystem of the SMT32F407xx is fairly complex:

[image]

If you were to just substitute a higher frequency crystal without reconfiguring the clock configuration you could exceed some maximum frequencies and get incorrect or unreliable operation.

With proper configuration the chip is capable of operating at maximum internal HCLK frequency of 168MHz with any of those crystals.

Comment: Beginner question, does the SMT32F407 MCU need a dedicated crystal to operate? I did read through the datasheet but I was not able to understand the recommended way to operate this MCU.

Comment: Not inherently. In the above diagram you can see the on-chip 16MHz RC oscillator acting as the system clock. Everything to the right of the vertical line is on the chip. Of course the internal RC clock may not be accurate enough for some purposes (eg. full speed USB requires +/-0.25% accuracy), so you may need the external crystal- read the reference manual etc. carefully.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean crystal and not crystal oscillator, you'll need to change the parallel caps and you'll need to be more careful about the component placement and board layout around the crystal.

Either way, these chips generate a main clock with a PLL.  The frequencies that you end up with for the various clocks will be derived from your main input clock frequency, and they'll be some integer ratio of the form \$P \frac{N}{M}\$, where ST has chosen the \$P\$ (which may be an integer or a rational number), and you can only choose integers for the \$N\$ and the \$M\$, and those only in ranges that ST has designed in.

So if you change the frequency of your main time base, you have to reconfigure the clock generation.

If you're depending on some specific clock frequency that you can only get with an \$8\mathrm{MHz}\$ or \$16\mathrm{MHz}\$ time base but there's no choice of \$N\$ and \$M\$ that will get you there with a \$25\mathrm{MHz}\$, then you need to re-think your design choices.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you want to do with the system and why, and what other clocks or devices there already are in the system.

Just for the MCU itself, increasing the crystal from 8 MHz to 16 MHz or 25 MHz means absolutely nothing to the MCU, assuming that the crystal works in the circuit.

The frequency still needs to be divided down to the same 1-2 MHz frequency for the PLL input and then multiplied with the PLL to have 168 MHz output. So that's why it does not matter to the MCU.

But for the crystal circuit itself, there is a difference.

Higher frequecy crystals can generally be found in smaller packages than lower frequency crystals, so higher frequency may allow to use smaller PCB area for the circuitry.

The oscillator inside the MCU to run the crystal requires certain parameters from the crystals (ESR and load capacitance for example) to work reliably with the crystal.

This means that for reliable operation, the higher the frequency is, the allowed load capacitance rating is smaller. And crystals with small load capacitance means that their frequency will get pulled more due to capacitance deviations in the circuit than crystals with higher load capacitance.

The F407 built-in bootloader supports DFU over USB to update the firmware. The DFU needs to detect the crystal frequency and can do it less reliably with higher frequency crystals (mentioned in AN2606).

So unless there is any need for 16 or 25 MHz, the 8 MHz crystal will do just fine.

However, in some cases, you might need to run the crystal or MCU at some specific frequency to fill some specific purpose. For example in some STM32F2 devices, the PLL jitter was so large that it prevented the PLL output to be used as the clock for Ethernet PHY. So one option was to use a 25 MHz MCU crystal and use the MCO pin to output the crystal clock to PHY without PLL.

So again, for the MCU, increasing the crystal speed has no benefit, it is just harder to get it working. But for the whole circuit in addition to the MCU, having a specific frequency crystal higher than 8 MHz might make sense (e.g. for audio master clock or Ethernet).